# SwiftUI - Passing a variable to Observable Object

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a view that's receiving an ID value from the previous view. I need to also take that ID value and pass it into an ObservableObject so that I can run a Firestore query on that ID. I'm at a loss as to how to grab that ID for my ObservableObject.

```
struct ItemView: View {
   var itemName: String
   var itemID: String
   @ObservedObject var items = getItemsData()
   // ..... etc
   }


 class getItemsData() {
    @Published var data = [items]()
    init() {
       let db = Firestore.firestore()
       db.collection("items").whereField("itemID", isEqualTo: *THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE ITEMID *),addSnapshotListner {(snap, err) in ...
}
```

So in the query call, I need to call the ItemID value to query based on that value that's defined at the top of the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your `getItemsData` class should inherit from ObservableObject

```
class GetItemsData: ObservableObject {...}
```

To get itemId into your GetItemsData instance, you can add a parameter to your `init()`

```
class GetItemsData: ObservableObject {
    init(itemId: String) {
        ...
    }
}
```

}

To tie it all together you have two choices. you could add an init to your ItemView like:

```
struct ItemView: View {
    let itemName: String
    let itemModel: GetItemsData
    init(itemName: String, itemID: String) {
        self.itemName = itemName
        itemModel = GetItemsData(itemId: itemID)
    }
}
```

I prefer instead to pass the observable object into the view, so it is more like a view model in MVVM

```
struct ItemView: View {
    let itemName: String
    let itemModel: GetItemsData
```

Comment: SwiftUI Views shouldn't init objects unless your property wrap them, otherwise they are lost because the View structs do not stick around

Answer (score 2):

If your `ObservableObject` has any state or is not located at top level view @tomcully way will end up with instantiating it with each parent view updating.

And also if you call an api inside `init()`, you will make many unnecessary api call.

**You can do like this:**

```
struct ItemView: View {
   let itemName: String
   let itemID: String
   @StateObject var itemsLoader = ItemsLoader()
   var body: some View {
     ...
     ForEach(itemsLoader.items) {
     ...
    .onAppear {
      itemsLoader.load(itemID)
    }
  }
}
class ItemsLoader: ObservedObject {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    var itemID: String = ""
    
    func load(_ id: String) {
        if itemID != id {
            itemID = id
            db.collection("items").whereField("itemID", isEqualTo: itemID),addSnapshotListner {(snap, err) in ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```